# Switch DB Connection to superuser role in Controller disables Row level security for JdbcTemplate update but not disabling for JPA save method

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jdbctemplate, row-level-security

When I clear the current user in `ThreadLocalContext` the new DB connection call returns default superuser connection. With this connection I can run update query on RLS enabled tables using JdbcTemplate. But if I try to call JPA save() method, I still get new row violates row-level security policy error

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

ThreadLocalStorage.clearDBUser();
System.out.print(DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource).getMetaData().getUserName());
//jdbcTemplate.update("update employee set is_deleted= true where id=?", id);
Employee emp = employeeService.findById(id);
emp.setIsDeleted(true);
employeeRepository.save(emp);
```

Output is `ERROR: new row violates row-level security policy for table "employee"`

As I have a `SELECT` `RLS` policy that filters deleted records, my `UPDATE` otherwise fails if DB role is not `superuser`. So, I have to make this switch happen before I call the JPA `save()` method.

ref SO [Ans1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76029501/3747396)

ref SO [Ans2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37561239/abstractroutingdatasource-doesnt-change-connection)

ref So [Ans3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76136715/spr-16876-transactionsynchronizationmanager-not-returning-correct-values-in-impl)

Followed the above answers but could not resolve in using JPA `save()` method call and bypass `RLS`